# Apply map function to every element of NumericRange wrapped in Array in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

I am having trouble trying to apply a map function to an Array with NumericRange.

```
val x: Array[NumericRange[Double]] = Array(-100.0 to 100.0 by 1.0)
val m = x.map(_ * theta1)
```

However, I am getting an error for this.
:13: error: value * is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]
           val m = x.map(_ * theta1)

So I understand that a NumericRange doesn't have a map function but what is an idiomatic way of doing it where I can apply a range and convert it to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x.map(_ * theta1)` you are trying to multiply `NumericRange` itself by theta1, I guess you need

```
val m: Array[NumericRange[Double]] = x.map(_.map(_ * theta1))
```

with types:

```
val m: Array[NumericRange[Double]] = x.map(range: NumericRange[Double] => range.map(_ * theta1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works. Is there a way to create an Array with the elements instead of having a NumericRange, when we create it itself ?

Comment: `(-100.0 to 100.0 by 1.0).toArray`

Comment: `Array.iterate(-100.0, 201)(_ + 1.0)`